# Can Not Parse Date Time String

Tags: swift, date-formatting

I am trying to parse this date string:

```
"2017-08-22T00:00:00+09:00"
```

...using a `DateFormatter` with this format:

```
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"
```

But it fails (i.e., returns nil).

**What am I missing??**

Comment: Can you show us an extract of your code when you try to parse your date string using a Dateformatter ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41577951/8294374 refer to this post

Comment: you need to espace the T in your string. `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz"` and don't forget to set your date formatter locale to `"en_US_POSIX"`

Comment: @LeoDabus That was it, **thank you** (it's 23:27+09:00 where I am, and it's been a long day...)